# horizontal page break

Tags: excel, vba

attempting to print PDF that are 2 pages tall, with page breaks at row number "numrows2" bu receiving

```
With Sheets("offer_Sheet").PageSetup
    .PrintArea = ("A2:H" & numrows)
    .HPageBreak.Location = ("A: " & numrows2)
    .FitToPagesWide = 1
    .FitToPagesTall = 2
    .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.1)
    .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.1)
    .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.1)
    .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.1)
    .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.1)
    .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.1)
    .Orientation = xlPortrait
End With
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular how to ask. Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. After doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: Are you looking for [`HPageBreaks.Add`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.hpagebreaks.add)? `PageSetup` doesn't have a `HPageBreak` property.

Comment: yes. i am trying to use hpagebreaks property

Answer (score 0):

`PageSetup` doesn't have an `HPageBreak` property.

If you're adding an `HPageBreak`, perhaps use [`HPageBreaks.Add`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.hpagebreaks.add):

```
Sub test()
    Dim numrows As Long, numrows2 As Long

    numrows = 20
    numrows2 = 10

    With Sheets("offer_Sheet")
        .HPageBreaks.Add (.Range("A" & numrows2))

        With .PageSetup
            .PrintArea = ("A2:H" & numrows)
            .FitToPagesWide = 1
            .FitToPagesTall = 2
            .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.1)
            .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.1)
            .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.1)
            .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.1)
            .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.1)
            .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.1)
            .Orientation = xlPortrait
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

Or if you're modifying an existing `HPageBreak`, perhaps:

```
Sub test2()
    Dim numrows As Long, numrows2 As Long

    numrows = 20
    numrows2 = 11

    With Sheets("offer_Sheet")
        If .HPageBreaks.Count > 0 Then
            Set .HPageBreaks(1).Location = .Range("A" & numrows2)
        End If

        With .PageSetup
            .PrintArea = ("A2:H" & numrows)
            .FitToPagesWide = 1
            .FitToPagesTall = 2
            .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.1)
            .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.1)
            .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.1)
            .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.1)
            .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.1)
            .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.1)
            .Orientation = xlPortrait
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```